# Toast.show than move to another Activity -> fatal exception: no dialog with id X was ever shown via Activity#showDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, toast

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16172): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 2 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at android.app.Activity.missingDialog(Activity.java:2600)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at android.app.Activity.dismissDialog(Activity.java:2585)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at com.proapps.eng.android.client.meeting_screen$1.handleMessage(meeting_screen.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
E/AndroidRuntime(16172):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  238):   Force finishing activity com.proapps.eng.android.client/.MainScreenActivity
W/ActivityManager(  238): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{2b54bd38 com.proapps.eng.android.client/.MainScreenActivity}
```

This exception is thrown after Toast.show() and right after that,start a new activity (the main one) instead of finish() the current.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
        // and update the progress bar.
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
        progDialog.setProgress(total);
        if (total <= 0){
            dismissDialog(typeBar);
            progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
            mail_sent_popup.show(); // mail sent popup
            startActivity(new Intent(cntx,MainScreenActivity.class));      
        // start the main instead of finishing this one.
        }
    }
};
```

When passing to the new activity it 'forgets' that the dialog was introduced in previous activity. What should I do?

BTW its not always throws ,only from time to time.
Thanx!!!

EDIT : Some more code (of the dialog thread)

```
private class ProgressThread extends Thread {

    // Class constants defining state of the thread
    final static int DONE = 0;
    final static int RUNNING = 1;

    Handler mHandler;
    int mState;
    int total;


    EditText name_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText phone_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText free_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    // Constructor with an argument that specifies Handler on main thread
    // to which messages will be sent by this thread.

    ProgressThread(Handler h) {
        mHandler = h;
    }

    // Override the run() method that will be invoked automatically when 
    // the Thread starts.  Do the work required to update the progress bar on this
    // thread but send a message to the Handler on the main UI thread to actually
    // change the visual representation of the progress. In this example we count
    // the index total down to zero, so the horizontal progress bar will start full and
    // count down.

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mState = RUNNING;   
        total = maxBarValue;
        while (mState == RUNNING) {

                // LONG JOB HERE

                }

            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", 0);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        }
    }

    // Set current state of thread (use state=ProgressThread.DONE to stop thread)
    public void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
    }
}
```

I guess dismissDialog(typeBar); is the wrong method to stop this thread. I don't know where I should put state=ProgressThread.DONE in the code

EDIT2:

I've added the code that declares the dialog and parts of onCreate of the Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    showDialog(2);
    ...
}


    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,mDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute,false);
    case 2:
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progDialog.setMessage("Sending...");
        progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
        progThread.start();
        return progDialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i've solved this issue:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
        // and update the progress bar.
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
        progDialog.setProgress(total);
        if (total <= 0){
            progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
//          dismissDialog(typeBar);     // PROBLEMATIC
            mail_sent_popup.show(); // mail sent popup
            startActivity(new Intent(cntx,MainScreenActivity.class));
// start the main instead of finishing this one.
        }
    }
};
```

Just commented the manual dismissDialog and let the thread die with progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a Dialog is owned by a single Activity. You can't show a dialog in ActivityA and then dismiss it in ActivityB.

Comment: mail_sent_popup.show();
            startActivity(new Intent(cntx,MainScreenActivity.class));     the first line show() toast dialog in current Activity, The second start new Activity right after. It has a timer of 3000 ms and it should dismiss by himself. not?

Comment: A `Toast` is not a `Dialog`. They are different things. The exception is being thrown from a call to dismissDialog() in meeting_screen.java at line 196. Maybe it is this call: `dismissDialog(typeBar);`? From what you've posted I can't see enough to understand the problem. Please show more code or explain better what the problem is.

Comment: It looks like the ProgressThread will die when you've set state to `ProgressThread.DONE`. The real problem seems to be how to make your progress-bar go away in the UI. But you've not shown how you are doing that. Post the code that you use to display the "progress bar" in the UI. Is this an Activity, a Dialog? How are you doing that?